# CSS not properly displayed on page

Tags: css

So I've set up some `div`'s on my page and while they look fine to me other people log on and the div will be improperly placed. I've looked and looked but can't find out why it's not loading the same for me, so if anyone can help in this it'd be appreciated. The `div` not showing correctly is

```
div.head-content
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -64px;
    left: 92.7%;
    margin-left: -360px;
    width: 131px;
    height: 46px;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to test it with only that. Please build a minimal example using for example http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: maybe because they have bigger screens or smaller

Comment: Can you share some more code, or have you uploaded it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah; they have bigger screens, but it is completely displaced. It's near the right hand side of my screen and it's more along the center of theirs.

Comment: ^or they haven't really refreshed their browser to contain latest changes.. I always refresh using ctrl+shift+r but like being said, fiddle could help - until then this is just guessing

Comment: It's not going to go anywhere without a link...

Comment: What other portion of the code would you want? That's the only div that's misplaced and the html to it is `code`<div class="header-content"><img src="/images/extra.png"></div>`code` Could it be because it's a div class and not a div id?

Comment: could you provide, maybe the entire webpage? that would be super helpful. you can't ask us to help you colour a half drawn picture, can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vivek is correct  try  this

> ```
>  #wrapper
>   { 
>     position:relative;
>     width:100%;
>     height:100%;
>      }
> ```

```
       .head-content 
               {
              display: block;
              position: absolute;
              top: -64px;
              left: 92.7%;
              margin-left: -360px;
              width: 131px;
              height: 46px;
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is either browser comparability or some alignment mistake.

if you are using wrapper make

```
#wrapper
{
  position:relative;
}
```

and it will do the job.

Unless you show us the entire code this is the most I can help.